# Ctrl+N doesn't open new query window in Management Studio (MS SQL 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   10.0.1600.22

But the keyboard shortcut of Ctrl+N is not doing anything. (Not opening the new query window)

I have check in Menu >> Options >> Environment >> Keyboard  but did not found any thing

Any Trick for opening new query window by shortcut key?

Comment: It is probably the same issue that causes Ctrl-R to randomly stop working in SQL Server 2012. Try the instructions suggested here... http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/735037/ctrl-r-not-working-in-ssms-2012

Comment: try resetting to default.

Answer (score -1):

Your copy is broken, or your keyboard is broken, of you have some other software causing problems. If you safe boot (or at least limit the start via winconfig or suchlike) you can see if disable other software solves it.

If you can open via mouse click on the New Query button or use the Menu options you at least have a work-around.